# Почему я не могу назначить вознаграждение (bounty)?

Tags: поддержка

Хотел объявить конкурс на этот вопрос: "[В предложном падеже: "в сЕти или в сетИ"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/415543)", но не вижу кнопки. Посмотрел, она у меня не на всех вопросах есть. С чем это связано?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bounty (оно же конкурс, оно же вознаграждение или награда) можно назначить только через 48 часов после появления вопроса. См. [справку](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).

Одна из причин для этого ограничения -- вопрос, за который назначено вознаграждение, невозможно закрыть. Этот период в 48 часов позволяет разобраться в сути вопроса, соответствует ли он теме сайта, и т. п.

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо.___